# Google maps coordinates view

Tags: google-maps

I have a regular map I can zoom in/out, move to North, South, East and West. Every time I do any action I would like to get a new map rectangular view coordinates, for example: lat from: x1, lat to: x2, lg from: y1, lg to: y2.

This is how I initialise map on my website:

```
function initMap() {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
}
```

Could you please guide me how can I achieve that?

Comment: What is "a regular map"?

Comment: Please, don't pretend that you didn't get a question. Regular map means just a simple basic view of the map. All I want to get is a coordinates of 4 corners.

Comment: You mean like http://maps.google.com?  How are you including it on your website?

Comment: I have update my questions. Thanks!

Comment: That is a [google-maps-api-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3) map.  Which coordinates do you want?  North, south, east and west bounds?

Comment: NorthEast, NorthWest, SouthEast, SouthWest - 4 points represented as lat lng. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add listeners to the map when the center or the bounds changes, get the bounds of the map and display your four corner coordinates.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed', displayBounds);
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'center_changed', displayBounds);

function displayBounds() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var north = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
    var east = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
    var south = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
    var west = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
    var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(north,east);
    var northWest = new google.maps.LatLng(north,west);
    var southEast = new google.maps.LatLng(south,east);
    var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(south,west);
    // NorthEast, NorthWest, SouthEast, SouthWest
    document.getElementById('coords').innerHTML = "NorthEast: "+northEast.toUrlValue(6)+"<br>NorthWest:" + northWest.toUrlValue(6) + "<br>SouthEast: "+southEast.toUrlValue(6) + "<br>SouthWest:"+southWest.toUrlValue(6)+"<br>";
}
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47805, -123.84716);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', displayBounds);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', displayBounds);
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', displayBounds);
}

function displayBounds() {
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var north = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
  var east = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
  var south = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
  var west = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
  var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(north, east);
  var northWest = new google.maps.LatLng(north, west);
  var southEast = new google.maps.LatLng(south, east);
  var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(south, west);
  // NorthEast, NorthWest, SouthEast, SouthWest
  document.getElementById('coords').innerHTML = "NorthEast: " + northEast.toUrlValue(6) + "<br>NorthWest:" + northWest.toUrlValue(6) + "<br>SouthEast: " + southEast.toUrlValue(6) + "<br>SouthWest:" + southWest.toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="coords"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```